# how to force a fragment to re run its own onCreateView

Tags: android

I have a tabHost which hosts 4 fragments.When the tabHost activity is created it creates and includes the fragments.How can i force a fragment to re create its view?meaning to re run the on createView.

**EDIT:** My first fragment consumes a web-service and updates a field in the parent activity.That field is read by my second fragment.But by the time the activity is instantiated the field in the parent activity is empty.So that's the reason I asked my question.I want the second Fragment to be re-drawn after the field is updated.Hope I'm clear now.Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Could you elaborate?

Comment: So just to be clear. You get some data and set it in a field of an activity, then the activity gets destroyed for some reason and the field is empty and you can't read it in the other fragment?

Comment: No,the activity isn't destroyed but since the fragments instantiate simultaneously by the time the second has created its view the field is empty,since the first hasn't yet updated it.hope i'm clear now

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (or Listener) design pattern. Basically what you do is create an interface like this (this is just an example)

```
interface DataListener {

   void dataHasArrived(Object data);

}
```

Your second fragment (the one that shows the data) should implement this (the object in the argument is the data that you want to present). The fragment that gets the data should have a reference to it (a field of type DataListener that contains the first fragment, you can set it in the parent activity). When the data is available you just call the method from the first fragment with the data as the argument and the implementation in the second fragment does the rest.

Comment: I don't know if it's just because we are talking about confusing/complicated fragments but seriously your answer seems a little weak. It's hard for me to follow. I wonder if that is why there are 0 upvotes? Also no matter how I provide a reference to the data for the Fragment, the Fragment will never update? Am I the only one who finds these fragments to be nothing but a pain? I am honeslty wondering what is their real world effectiveness and usefulness. It just seems like everything is easier without Fragments